# How to install miniupnpc as a python module on windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pip, miniupnpc

I want to use UPnP in my python scripts, so I tried to install miniupnpc through `pip install miniupnpc`. But It causes an error a little bit after the installation starts:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

         cwd: C:\Users\sammy\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-jrjs0fss\miniupnpc\
    Complete output (4 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
    ----------------------------------------
```

I checked the GitHub but I don't know where to find the tools I need to compile the python module or how to use them.

Comment: It gives the same error when I download the module from github and try to install it with `python setup.py install`, so it's not a problem with `pip`. There is something missing in the module's files

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/miniupnp/miniupnp/issues/159

Comment: Most of the potentially useful appveyor links are dead unfortunately

Comment: Yes... maybe you could open another issue there or ask them because they will most likely know how to solve your problem better

Comment: Any updates a year later?

Comment: In the end I stopped trying, very hard to come across/use UPnP tools for python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe at the time the library was a little bit bugged, I never worked out the issue in the end, I recommend looking for other tools.

It is also worth mentioning I wasn't a very good programmer back then, I now actually understand the nature of libraries and packages.